# Combinations of two character alphanumeric - how many

Tags: combinatorics

For some reason I cannot find this answer on Google, and I am not good enough in this particular area to figure it out on my own.

> Using the alphabet, letters $A$-$Z$, and the numbers $0$-$9$, how many unique combinations are possible. Combinations like $AB$, $AA$, $A1$, etc.? Each two character code must be unique and using all possible combinations.

Comment: If order matters: $\frac{36!}{(36-2)!}=1260$. If order does not matter: $\binom{36}{2}=630$.

Comment: That makes sense - easy for some. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @barak manis: OP gave an example showing AA is acceptable, so you should include cases where the characters match

Comment: @barakmanos From the examples, it looks like replacement is ok. Thus 36 choose 2 wouldn't be right.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yep, I agree. In that case the answer is simply $36^2$ (assuming that order has to matter, since it would be really unusual if it didn't).

Answer (score 4):

You have $36$ choices for the first character, and $36$ for the second, so $36\cdot 36=1296$ in all

Comment: You did not refer to the (extremely unusual) case where order does not matter (e.g., AB and BA are considered the same combination). I suppose that OP did not mean for this to be the case here, but since it is not mentioned in the question, you might want to address this case as well...

Comment: I I thought would just confuse things here.